# How to select data from listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform to add information in a table in Excel and the results appear in the listbox.

The problem is when I want to modify the information in the listbox, it gives me "No row is selected".

This is the code in the edit button:

```
If Selected_List = 0 Then

    MsgBox "No row is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "edit"
    Exit Sub
    
End If
   
Me.txtRowNumber2.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 0) + 1

'Assign the value

adminpanel.TextBox9.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 1)
    
adminpanel.TextBox10.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 2)

adminpanel.TextBox11.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 3)

adminpanel.TextBox12.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 4)

adminpanel.TextBox13.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 5)

adminpanel.TextBox14.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 6)

adminpanel.TextBox15.Value = Me.ListBox2.List(Me.ListBox2.ListIndex, 7)
           

adminpanel.CommandButton28.Caption = "edit"

MsgBox "Please make the required changes and click on update to save."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which is to replace

If Selected_List = 0 Then

```
MsgBox "No row is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "edit"
Exit Sub
End If
```

with

```
   If ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "There are no items selected to delete"

    End If
```

i am glad to share with you the solution 
thanks